# Firebase ChildAdded Observer is Retrieving Data That Doesn't Exist

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

I am using a child added observer to check if a user gets a new notification while using my app...

```
 func newLikeNotificationObserver() {
    notifHandle = Database.database().reference().child("notifications").child(FirebaseDatabase.system.CURRENT_USER_ID).observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if !snapshot.exists() {
            print("ERROR")
            return
        }
        let id = snapshot.key
        print(id)
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>  {
            print("ADDED TO LIST")
            let notif = Notifications(notifID: id, data: dict)
            self.notifications.insert(notif, at: 0)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

The strange issue that I am having is that despite no data being written to my database for when a user likes his/her own posts, the observer is triggered and a Notification is inserted to the array containing the actual user notifications. When I print out the notif-ID to see if I can find it in my DB, its no-where to be found. Can anybody see were I may have gone wrong?

Also, I am removing the observer in the deinit method and adding it in viewdidload(). Thanks in advance

Comment: There's really not enough info included to answer the question; You state the code is called in *viewDidLoad* - which view? Is it a view that's used more than once? Do you have observers or Firebase related code anywhere else in the app? Is notifHandle a class variable or perhaps included in a singleton somewhere else? Is the view actually being dismissed at some point?

Answer (score 0):

The correct place to put event observers is in viewDidAppear and remove them in viewWillDisappear.

I think its likely that a previous observer is not being removed and is returning bad data. restart the computer and see if it occurs on the initial running of the app, or only on subsequent launches

Comment: According to this article: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/best-practices-for-ios-uiviewcontroller_6.html. View will appear is the place in the controllers life cycle to add your observers

Comment: I think the point being made is that doing it once in ViewDidLoad is not the ideal place to do it.  Whether it’s done in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear is I think irrelevant, given the async nature of the call.

Comment: I understand, however, I cant even trace back where a datasource can even be created. For the cell to populate my notification collectionview, something would need to be appended to its datasource, but it just isnt the case.